# boot from live dvd continue using usb

Tags: boot, live-usb, chroot, livedvd

I've got a bit of a weird problem. I need to get a live version of ubuntu running but the bios hangs/crashes when a bootable usb drive is present in the usb (3.0) drive. I can boot using a linux live disk but the dvd player crashes after about 30/40 minutes (and I'm going to need several hours) and takes several hours to become operational again. So I was wondering if it is possible to boot from a dvd and continue on a usb drive with linux installed on it (so not a live usb). Can it be done with chroot?

Answer (score 0):

Chroot is an operation that changes the apparent root directory for the current running process and their children. A program that is run in such a modified environment cannot access files and commands outside that environmental directory tree. So Be careful..

Comment: I know and that is what I want to do with every process that might need access to files. If I've got the same version of ubuntu it should work more or less. A better option would be to tell the live disk to restart it's session using the usb without going through the bios. Besides I've disconnected the hard drive so the only thing that can be broken is the ubuntu installation on that usb drive. I'm sorry but your answer doesn't really answer my question

Comment: Solution 1- try by removing CMOS Battery,

Comment: If not Working till, try to update Bios...

Comment: bios has already been reset and I don't want to update the bios since the owner already ordered a new one. This is just for file retrieval and him being able to do his work while he waits for the new computer to arrive. Besides if the bios update goes as wonky as this pc is currently acting it will really become a 2,5 kg paper weight and he will be without a computer for a few weeks.

Comment: try to install via Fresh bootable USB

Comment: I already tried 3 different usb drive all freshly made. I tried 2 isos that have been hash md5 checked to be correct. If I hadn't tried that I wouldn't have asked here.

Comment: then you can try surely Chroot

Comment: I fixed it by making a symbolic link from the dvd device to the usb device and mounting the same usb device to /cdrom. As long as the versions are identical it should work